# implement low relevancy to Out-of-Stock products while searching

Tags: solr, nopcommerce, solrnet

I have indexed stockAvailability field in solr schema for product & if product is not in stock then this stockAvailability field contains false. otherwise it contains true.

I am using solr to search products and when I search product, I want out of stock products at the end of search result from solr.

What will be the query for this feature..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on which query parser you're using, you can apply a large boost to any documents that match your boost query:

```
&bq=inStock:true^999
```

This will apply an extra boost to any documents about products that are in stock. Adjust 999 to something suitable for your other boost values.

If you need a more general way (for certain words, etc.), have a look at the [Solr Relevancy Faq](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F) of how to apply a boost to any documents that doesn't contain a term.